# Error al tratar de crear una vista en SQL Developer

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estuve tratando de intentar crear una vista en SQL Developer pero, me da un error de columnas duplicadas.
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
CREATE VIEW VW_FACTURAS_POR_CLIENTE_2021 AS
SELECT C.NIT, C.NOMBRE, F.SERIE, F.NUMERO, F.FECHA, P.NOMBRE, DF.CANTIDAD
FROM CLIENTES C, FACTURAS F, PRODUCTOS P, DETALLE_FACTURA DF
WHERE C.CLIENTE=F.CLIENTE
AND DF.SERIE=F.SERIE
AND DF.NUMERO=F.NUMERO
AND DF.CODIGO_PRODUCTO=P.CODIGO_PRODUCTO
AND TO_CHAR(F.FECHA, 'RRRR')='2021'
ORDER BY C.NIT, F.SERIE, F.NUMERO
```

El error que me da es el siguiente:

> Informe de error - ORA-00957: duplicate column name
> 00957. 00000 -  "duplicate column name"
> *Cause:
> *Action:

También revise si era mi consulta la que estaba mala pero, a la hora de ejecutar la consulta no me da ningún error. Mi código de la consulta es el siguiente:

```
SELECT C.NIT, C.NOMBRE, F.SERIE, F.NUMERO, F.FECHA, P.NOMBRE, DF.CANTIDAD
FROM CLIENTES C, FACTURAS F, PRODUCTOS P, DETALLE_FACTURA DF
WHERE C.CLIENTE=F.CLIENTE
AND DF.SERIE=F.SERIE
AND DF.NUMERO=F.NUMERO
AND DF.CODIGO_PRODUCTO=P.CODIGO_PRODUCTO
AND TO_CHAR(F.FECHA, 'RRRR')='2021'
ORDER BY C.NIT, F.SERIE, F.NUMERO
```

El código de la consulta no varia mucho con respecto al código para crear la vista, simplemente no puedo ver donde esta mi error. No sé si es un error en mi código o talvez podría ser un problema de integridad de la base de datos. De antemano les agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: No entiendo por qué la etiqueta MySQL si tienes un error ORA que parece indicar que trabajas en Oracle. Es Oracle o MySQL ? Y para cualquiera de las dos, qué versión es? Evita indicar la versión de SQL Developer, que es el cliente y no es lo mismo que la base de datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba quitando la ambiguedad de la columna `NOMBRE`, que la obtienes de dos tablas (y seguro que con datos diferentes, pero pues, tienen el mismo nombre)

```
CREATE VIEW VW_FACTURAS_POR_CLIENTE_2021 AS
SELECT 
C.NIT, 
C.NOMBRE NOMBRE_CLIENTE, 
F.SERIE, 
F.NUMERO NUMERO_FACTURA, 
F.FECHA FECHA_FACTURA, 
P.NOMBRE NOMBRE_PRODUCTO, 
DF.CANTIDAD
FROM 
CLIENTES C, FACTURAS F, PRODUCTOS P, DETALLE_FACTURA DF
WHERE 
C.CLIENTE=F.CLIENTE
AND DF.SERIE=F.SERIE
AND DF.NUMERO=F.NUMERO
AND DF.CODIGO_PRODUCTO=P.CODIGO_PRODUCTO
AND TO_CHAR(F.FECHA, 'RRRR')='2021'
ORDER BY C.NIT, F.SERIE, F.NUMERO
```